# Find and replace regex in a loop in Python

Tags: python, regex, search, replace

I have JSON data in a text file.  The file has {limit:{track:20}} errors strewn across the file.  The number 20 in the string keeps changing randomly.  I am using the following regex "({"limit":{"track":\d+}})" without the first and last parentheses.  It works fine when I use it manually in SublimeText to search the expression and replace it with a blank space.  However, when I try to use it in a loop the regex engine throws error.  The following is the code:

```
 import sys
 import re

 f = sys.argv['/Users/mycomp/Documents/2015/Travel/I2015-10.5.2015.txt']
 find = re.compile(r "(\{"limit"\:\{"track"\:\d+\}\})")
 replace = sys.argv[ ]
 with open (f, 'r') as myfile:
      s = myfile.read()
 ret = re.sub(find, replace, s)
```

gives me a syntax error.  I am a novice programmer.

Comment: USe single quotes around your regex pattern. You can see the syntax highlighting in your post, you are closing the strings.

Comment: Please provide an example file. It makes debugging always way easier.

Comment: Please read the guidlines for asking qustions here.  They say quite clearly: post the error message you are getting.

Answer (score 1):

Your regular expression needs some cleaning up. For example you have quotes around "limit" in your regex, but your sample data doesn't show this.

Also your Python code is doing some bizarre things. For example,

```
f = sys.argv['/Users/mycomp/Documents/2015/Travel/I2015-10.5.2015.txt']
```

doesn't make sense, you need to use an integer inside of the `argv` list.

```
import sys
import re

f = '/Users/mycomp/Documents/2015/Travel/I2015-10.5.2015.txt'
find = re.compile(r'{limit:{track:\d+}}')
replace = ''
with open (f, 'r') as myfile:
     s = myfile.read()
     ret = find.sub(replace, s)
     print ret  # will print your file with instances of your matched regex removed.
```